# Setting Pre-loaded text to Black and Typed in Text to White in a UITextView

Tags: ios, uitextview, uicolor

I am trying to achieve something which may or may not be possible, but if it is, I have not found a way.

I have a `UITextView` that is populated with the words "Additional Notes: " in the form of a placeholder (because you can't directly have placeholder texts with a `UITextView`).

When I tap on the `UITextView`, it creates a new line character and the user can start typing.

What I want to achieve is for the "Additional Notes: " text to be in Gray, but the typed in text to appear in white.

Is this possible?

In my view, I have:

```
- (BOOL)textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView {

    if([[textView text] isEqualToString:@"Additional Notes: "]){
        [textView setText:@"Additional Notes: \n"];
    }
    return YES;

}

- (BOOL)textViewShouldEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView {

    if([[[textView text] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]] isEqualToString:@""]){
        [textView setText:@"Additional Notes: "];
    }
    return YES;
}
```

In the `viewDidLoad`, I set the text to Grey:

```
self.notesTextView.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
```

In the `shouldChangeTextInRage`, I tried putting the colour white in there with an if condition, but what happens is, the "Additional Notes: " changes to white as well as soon as I start typing.

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
    self.notesTextView.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    if ([text isEqualToString:@"\n"])
    {
        [textView resignFirstResponder];
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Is what I'm trying to achieve, possible? If so, how would I go about doing it?

Comment: Use NSAttributedString

Comment: Thanks Larme - sorry but how would I use that in this case with text pre-loaded and then entered in by the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find the range of the @"Additional Notes: " substring using the

```
NSRange *rangeOfPlaceholder =[[textView text] rangeOfString:@"Additional Notes: "];
```

and then create attributedtext and set it to the textView as follows in your textview delegates while editing:-

```
NSMutableAttributedString *attString=[[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:textView.text];
[attString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor grayColor] range:rangeOfPlaceholder];
[attString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor whiteColor] range:rangeOfRemainingEnteredText];

[textView setAttributedText:attString];
```

Comment: Thanks so much @borncrazy again for your help. I think the idea is almost there. I set rangeOfRemainingEnteredText to = self.notesTextView.text and I did that code in the shouldChangeTextInRange - it's still changing both the Placeholder and the entered text to white, but I'm going to try work on this and see

Comment: rangeOfRemainingEnteredText = NSMakeRange(rangeOfPlaceholder.start+rangeOfPlaceholder.lenght, [attString length]-rangeOfPlaceholder.length); (or something like that)

Comment: Try this:- **    NSRange rangeOfRemainingEnteredText = NSMakeRange(rangeOfPlaceholder.length ,[[textView text] length] -rangeOfPlaceholder.length );**

Comment: That works really well @borncrazy - just two minor things now.. how would I adjust the font (because when you start typing, it reduces the font size to the default 12) and 2) the first letter you type is in grey but the moment you type the second letter onwards, it changes the typed text to all white (so it's the first character that starts of grey but then turns to white after the second letter is typed) - thanks again

Comment: 1) UIFont *font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14.0f];
[attString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:font range:NSMakeRange(0, lengthOfString)]; 
2) For this I guess the range is somewhere causing the problem, you can figure that out.:)

Comment: Thanks @borncrazy - that did the trick nd a bit of playing around got this to work. For the second time today, many thanks for your assistance! Really appreciate it :)